# How can I create a two thread one for sending video and others for receiving video at the sam time in UDP python

Tags: python, opencv, sockets, udp, python-multithreading

Hi guy I am making a UDP protocol to create a live chat between server and client I have written a code for server to send video to client and vice versa which work fine.but right now I am trying to make it to sending and receiving at the same time I tried using two thread for both client and server but seems like I am getting this error

> 2022-03-27 04:51:48.211 python3[6961:9402560] WARNING: nextEventMatchingMask should only be called from the Main Thread! This will throw an exception in the future.

And it is not working [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjZ54.png)

here is my code

server.py

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, imutils, socket
import time
import base64
import threading


BUFF_SIZE = 65536

message = b'Hello'

def create_UDP_Socket():
    global server_socket
    global host_ip
    global host_name
    global port
    
    try:

        server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, BUFF_SIZE)
        host_name = socket.gethostname()
        print(host_name)
        host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
        print(host_ip)
        port = 9998
    except socket.error as msg:
        print(f'Create socket error : {msg}')
      
def binding_socket():
    try:
        socket_address = (host_ip, port)
        server_socket.bind(socket_address)
        print('listening at :-', socket_address)
    except socket.error as msg:
          print(f'Binding socket error : {msg}')

def broadcast():
    print('Waiting for client to connect to broadcast')
    while True:
        
        vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        fps, st, frames_to_count, cnt = (0, 0, 20, 0)
        # receive request from user 
        msg, client_addr = server_socket.recvfrom(BUFF_SIZE)
        print('GOT connection from ', client_addr)
        
        # Check user request
        if msg == b'request broadcast':

            print(f'Receveing request broadcasting from client{client_addr}')
            print(f'Broadcast video to user :{client_addr}')
            Width = 400
            while vid.isOpened():
                _,frame = vid.read()
                frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=Width)
                endcoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 80])
                message = base64.b64encode(buffer)
                server_socket.sendto(message,client_addr)
            # print(f'Sending to client : {client_addr}')
                frame = cv2.putText(frame, 'FPS: ' + str(fps), (10, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                cv2.imshow('Transmitting Video to Client (q:quit)',frame)
                key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

                if key == ord('q'):
                    server_socket.close()
                    break
                if cnt == frames_to_count:
                    try:
                        fps = round(frames_to_count/(time.time()-st))
                        st=time.time()
                        cnt=0
                    except:
                        pass
                cnt+=1
        else:
            print(f'Client at address {client_addr} wrong request')
            msg = b'wrong request'
            server_socket.sendto(msg,client_addr)
            break

def receive_broadcast():

    # wating for client to send request
    print('waiting for client to connect')

    # receive connection from client
    msg, client_addr = server_socket.recvfrom(BUFF_SIZE)
    
    print(f'Connect to : {client_addr}')
    server_socket.sendto(message,client_addr)
    print('Receciving a broadcast')
      

    fps, st, frames_to_count, cnt = (0, 0, 20, 0)
    while True:
        
        # receiving video fromm client
        packet, _ = server_socket.recvfrom(BUFF_SIZE)
        data = base64.b64decode(packet,b' /')
        npdata = np.fromstring(data, dtype=np.uint8)
        frame = cv2.imdecode(npdata, 1)
        frame = cv2.putText(frame, 'FPS: ' + str(fps), (10, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow("RECEIVING VIDEO from Client (q:quit)", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord('q'):
            server_socket.close()
            break
        if cnt == frames_to_count:
                try:
                    fps = round(frames_to_count/(time.time()-st))
                    st=time.time()
                    cnt=0
                except:
                    pass
        cnt+=1

def start():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=broadcast)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=receive_broadcast)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    


create_UDP_Socket()
binding_socket()

start()
```

client.py

```
import cv2, imutils, socket
import numpy as np
import time
import base64
import threading
BUFF_SIZE = 65536
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
client_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, BUFF_SIZE)
host_name = socket.gethostname()
host_ip =  socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
print('Host ip: - ',host_ip)
port = 9998


def receive_broadcast():
    #request to connect
    message =  b'request broadcast'
    client_socket.sendto(message, (host_ip, port))
    print('test: ',message)
    print('Send Request to a server for Broadcast video')
    fps, st, frames_to_count, cnt = (0, 0, 20, 0)
    while True:
        packet, server_add = client_socket.recvfrom(BUFF_SIZE)
        if packet == b'wrong request':
            print('server reject ')
            break 

        #print(f"connected to  server:{server_add}")
        data = base64.b64decode(packet,b' /')
        npdata = np.fromstring(data, dtype=np.uint8)
        frame = cv2.imdecode(npdata, 1)
        frame = cv2.putText(frame, 'FPS: ' + str(fps), (10, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow("RECEIVING VIDEO from Server (q:quit)", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord('q'):
            client_socket.close()
            break
        if cnt == frames_to_count:
                try:
                    fps = round(frames_to_count/(time.time()-st))
                    st=time.time()
                    cnt=0
                except:
                    pass
        cnt+=1
    

def broadcast():

    # request to connect
    message = b'request to connect to server'
    client_socket.sendto(message, (host_ip, port))
    print('test: ',message)
    print('Sending Broadcasting')

    while True:
        vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        fps, st, frames_to_count, cnt = (0, 0, 20, 0)
        msg, client_addr = client_socket.recvfrom(BUFF_SIZE)
        print('GOT connection from ', client_addr)
        Width = 400
        while vid.isOpened():
            _,frame = vid.read()
            frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=Width)
            endcoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 80])
            message = base64.b64encode(buffer)
            client_socket.sendto(message,client_addr)
            frame = cv2.putText(frame, 'FPS: ' + str(fps), (10, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.imshow('Transmitting Video to Server (q:quit)',frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

            if key == ord('q'):
                client_socket.close()
                break
            if cnt == frames_to_count:
                try:
                    fps = round(frames_to_count/(time.time()-st))
                    st=time.time()
                    cnt=0
                except:
                    pass
            cnt+=1


def start():

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=broadcast)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=receive_broadcast)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

start()
```

Comment: This is just an warning and not a error. This shouldn't affect your code/output as of now.

Comment: @Vaibhav The thing is the video from CV is not showing IDK why